# get_the_excerpt adding unwanted links to output html

Tags: excerpt

I can hardly believe this is happening, but I have

```
if ($text == "") {
     $text = get_the_excerpt();
    //  $text = "this will be the text";
}
```

When I call `echo $text` subsequently with the simple string (now commented out), then I get that string, but when I use get_the_excerpt then `the_title` above and `$text` get wrapped in a link to the post (see `**` below). Any idea how I can prevent this?

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card card--big">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <article <?php post_class(); ?>>

                <div class="card__image" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $image[0]; ?>")> </div>

                <div class="card__text">
                    <h4>
                       <?php the_title(); ?>
                    </h4>
                    <?php 
                        echo $text; 
                    ?>
                </div>
            </article>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is what comes out

```
<div class="card card--big">
        <a href="//localhost:3000/2016/amsterdam-tapas-barra-pikoteo/">
            **</a>**<article class="post-5261 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-restaurant-reviews">
**<a href="//localhost:3000/2016/amsterdam-tapas-barra-pikoteo/">**

                <div class="card__image" style="background-image:url(//localhost:3000/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Pikoteo-tapas-Amsterdam.jpg" )=""> </div>

                **</a>**<div class="card__text">**<a href="//localhost:3000/2016/amsterdam-tapas-barra-pikoteo/">**
                    <h4>
                       Amsterdam tapas, traditional and modern: Barra and Pikoteo                    </h4>
                    A long time ago____ 
                    **</a>**
                    <a href="//localhost:3000/2016/amsterdam-tapas-barra-pikoteo/">[…]</a>
            </div>
         </article>            
    </div>
```

I'm using OSX, MAMP and no plugins

Comment: @N00b - interesting question, as if inject the $text elsewhere there is no problem. I've added the full html.

Comment: You are wrapping the whole thing with `<a>` tag. Everything inside it is a link.

Comment: What exactly do you want to be a link? Whole `<article>` is currently a link.

Comment: I know why there is a link around [...] (which I will look up how to delete next), but there are two other links now inserted in the output html which I did not deliberately put in their. I just want the article (and hence its contents) to be a single link. The links are NOT added when I use the simple string

Comment: :-( that didn't change anything. This is soooo weird

Comment: You have broken `a` tag. That's why you are seeing that text wrapped in  a tag. another thing you can not wrap `article`, `div` into a tag.

Comment: It depends what `HTML` is being used: in `HTML5` you can put pretty much anything inside `<a>` tag that isn't interactive (_e.g_ other links or buttons).

Comment: Yes true. But reading at title seems like this is the issue!

Comment: OP, it wouldn't hurt if you told us, what development tools and browser you're using.

Comment: OSX and MAMP - I updated the question

Comment: Are you seeing the extra anchor tags in the actual source of the page or via a browser inspection tool?  Chrome will interpret your code and, in certain conditions, add missing closing tags or insert code you didn't write (`<tobdy>` anyone?).  Wrapping the entire article with an anchor could possibly cause this.

Comment: @jdm2112 This definitely looks like what is happening here - the browser is trying to "fix" it by making sure everything is linked.

Comment: I think that was it. the_excerpt was adding a link for the 'read more' and that seemed to be causing the issue. Lesson learnt!